# Spark-Application to Local Directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, spark-submit

**PROBLEM**

Spark Application error due to Mkdirs failed to create.
I'm using spark 1.6.3 unable to save output on my local dir

```
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/zooms/output/sample1/sample1.txt/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201709251225_0005_m_000000_10
 (exists=false, cwd=file:/grid/1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/zooms/appcache/application_1504506749061_0086/container_e01_1504506749061_0086_01_000003)
```

**Updated logs**

```
17/09/25 13:39:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 10, worker3.hdp.example.com): java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/zooms/output/sample1/sample1.txt/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201709251339_0005_m_000000_10 (exists=false, cwd=file:/grid/1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/zooms/appcache/application_1504506749061_0099/container_e01_1504506749061_0099_01_000003)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:442)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:930)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:823)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1191)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1183)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Code:**

```
val output = "file:///home/zooms/output/sample1/sample1.txt" 
result.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(output)
```

**SOLUTION**

Make sure that the whole cluster have access to the local or specific directory. 
On my case, the cluster or the spark executors doesn't have access to the specific directory.

Comment: can you provide more error logs and the code line that is throwing that error?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan added updated logs

Comment: Maybe you do not have permission to write to that folder?

Comment: i already added zooms (user account) to hdfs group

Comment: Its hard to help without your code. can you share your code of saving the output?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan added code saving my output

Comment: your error message gives output folder as `/home/zooms/output/sample1/...` but you have used `/home/zooms/20170926/...` in your code. So either you pasted wrong code or you are modifying the ouput path somewhere else.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan i pasted wrong code it should be `file:///home/zooms/output/sample1/sample1.txt`

Comment: thats alright but if you still look at your error message, there is additional path being appended to the final saving path `_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201709251339_0005_m_000000_10`. Now the question is how that string path is being appended? think about it, research in your code, and analyze. ;)

Comment: That `_temporary/...` is generated by spark, in my laptop its working but in spark-submit it's not working, already tried including zooms to hadoop, yarn and hdfs group but still it doesn't work...

Comment: @JozefDúc what else can I set for the permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my question. 
Since i'm running on a cluster mode or client mode, workers won't able to create the directory on each node unless you define it. Use 
`spark-submit -v --master local ...`

References: 
[Writing files to local system with Spark in Cluster mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786093/writing-files-to-local-system-with-spark-in-cluster-mode/40786542)

[Why does Spark job fails to write output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497887/why-does-spark-job-fails-to-write-output)